# Overwrite last field in last line using awk

Tags: awk

I would like to overwrite the last field (2 fields in total) of the last line of a file with the value -9. I am using this command:

```
awk 'END{$2=-9}1' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

but it doesn't seem to work (no replacement is done). Why's that? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The END block condition is processed after the last line of the last input file. $0, $1, $2,... is empty in your END block, you can test it by printing $0 and or $1, $2.

Comment: If your file is large and uncompressed, then you should consider the unix utility [`dd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29).

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to print the *previous* line, and then you can manipulate the *last* line in the END block before it has already been printed:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print prev} {prev = $0} END {$2=-9; print}'
```

Comment: You forgot the ``file`` xP

Answer (score 3):

the END section is executed AFTER processing the last line so you're assigning `$2` a value after the last line has been printed.

There's also no guarantee that $2 or $0 or any of the fields will be preserved in the END section (POSIX doesn't specify it) but IF in your awk, $2, etc ARE preserved then what you need is something like:

```
awk '
NR>1{print prev}
{prev=$0}
END {$2=-9; print}
'
```

If they aren't then you need to create a $0 first:

```
awk '
NR>1{print prev}
{prev=$0}
END {$0=prev; $2=-9; print}
'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `tac` + `awk`:

```
tac file.txt|awk 'NR==1{$NF="-9";}1'|tac >new_file.txt
```

**PS**: I prefer @glenn solution.